# how to make macro replacement text into a string in C / C++

Tags: c-preprocessor

I wonder if it is possible to create a string literal containing the replacement text of a preprocessor macro.

E. g. one has defined:

```
#define Number 2.847
```

And the program is supposed to output this number as a string. I tried:

```
#define M(a) #a
int main() {
   cout << M(Number) << endl;
}
```

But it outputs "Number" instead of "2.847".

Is there a way to make it work without changing the definition of `Number`? Since this definition might be in a standard header which does not even exist as a file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to do another pass. Typically:

```
#include <iostream>   

#define NUMBER      2.847

#define STRING(a)   #a
#define XSTRING(a)  STRING(a)

int main() {
   std::cout << XSTRING(NUMBER) << '\n';
}
```